# Как объединенные колонки в таблице разбить и поставить туда одинаковые значения?

Tags: php, html, dom, table

Есть таблица в которой для некоторых полей используется `colspan` и `rowspan`. Но мне нужно, чтобы PHP код убирал это объединение и допустим вместо `colspan=2` делал 2 ячейки и заполнял их идентичными данными, которые были в этом поле с атрибутом `colspan=2`.

Comment: Если  вы почитаете про domDocument, то уж с colspan вы справитесь очень легко. С rowspan чуть сложнее. Пробуйте, появятся проблемы с кодом, обращайтесь. А писать код за авторов вопроса - не лучший стиль

Answer (score 0):

Это не вопрос из области PHP, а скорее по DOM. Как вам советует @splash58, почитайте про табличные теги, а PHP это средство вывода, а не верстки.